# multiple thread writing to the same boolean

Tags: java, concurrency

I am working on a graph ( nodes and vertices ) partitioning algorithm.

I use multiple threads to try and identify certain regions inside the graph.

Once a node has been identified as a part of a region, I set a `boolean marked` to true for the node object.

Multiple threads can attempt to mark the same node at the same time.

Currently I use synchronization to ensure nothing bad happens.

However since I **never** read the value of marked till after all the threads have finished processing. Would it be possible for me to get rid of the synchronization code? In other words can anything go wrong when concurrently writing to a boolean variable?

Comment: Is marked ever set to false when it's been set to true?

Comment: nope. just set to true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can anything go wrong when concurrently writing to a boolean variable?

Yes and no.  Certainly the resulting value won't be somehow corrupted however it is going to be non-deterministic on which of the updates gets set on the field and when these updates are seen by other threads -- if at all.

If you have multiple threads making decisions using the value of this boolean, you have to at some point provide memory synchronization.  Making the field `volatile` costs very little and unless you have evidence that it is a performance problem, not having the field be `volatile` is most likely premature optimization.  If you are comparing and setting then an `AtomicBoolean` is recommended which wraps a `volatile boolean` and provides higher level methods like `compareAndSet(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

No, nothing could go wrong when multiple threads write to the same boolean value, but there can be a problem of reading the value (even a long time) later in a different thread. You should at least mark the variables as `volatile` to prevent the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said there is no risk of corruption or incorrect values to the boolean if you are simply trying to set it to the same value from multiple threads.

However, you may not even need that

> I never read the value of marked till after all the threads have finished processing.

You obviously need some sort of barrier to synchronize the coordinating thread with the worker threads (such as [Thread.join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) or [CountdownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) or your primitive du jour) and nearly all of those *already* provide a happens-before relationship that will make all your marks visible to the coordinator thread.

Having that single point of synchronization also just happens to be cheaper than reading a large number of volatiles (and I wouldn't call that premature optimization, simply eliding the need for volatiles)

Comment: thanks.. that makes sense. ( I was using thread.join() ) along with  using volatile booleans.I will use booleans instead of volatile booleans

Answer (score 1):

In theory, no, but I wouldn't mind declaring the variable `volatile`. Volatile keyword ensures atomic access.

(Provided that the order of the writes do not matter and all reads occur after all writes.)

Comment: It's not about atomic access which always happens with a `boolean` unless you are perming a test and set operation which `volatile` doesn't save you from.  It's about order of operations and memory visibility.

Comment: Unless there is proper synchronization, it is possible that a reader thread would read "false" although a writer thread set the boolean to "true". There *is* a visibility issue in what the OP describes.

Answer (score 0):

No. If the order of the writes to that variable do not matter.

Comment: The problem is that the writes might *never* be observable by the reader threads.

Comment: @assylias Even though "I never read the value of marked till after all the threads have finished processing"? Can you explain?

Comment: The fact that the writing thread has finised its job does not mean that the changes made have been properly published and can be read from another thread.

Comment: Interesting. Is it because it takes a finite amount of time to "publish" the changes and we are not clearly marking the boundaries of that "publish" operation? Since the change is atomic, the reader threads might read before the change is done publishing and hence there's a chance it might never be read?

Comment: Without appropriate synchronization, they might never be published. In theory, a JVM that determines that a thread sets a variable without synchronization and never reads that variable later on would be allowed to treat that write as a no-op while complying with the Java Memory Model. In that case the change will never be published... In practice this is unlikely to happen and many "things" do synchronize the code. For example, calling `writingThread.join()` from the reading thread would be enough to make the write visible.